# TailwindCSS background-color behind all content

Tags: html, css, tailwind-css

I'm trying to design a page with a set background color, but I'm having some difficulty.

I've got a parent container that sets the height with `min-h-screen` as well as assigns the background color. My inner child doesn't inherent height from the parent, so the behavior is off. I can fix this by using `h-screen` in the parent, but then any overflow content in the child isn't within the background.

I've thought of a few solutions, some using flexbox and another using `overflow-scroll`, but none of these feel like the proper solution. I was curious if someone could point out the correct way to solve this issue?

Here's an example of the undesirable behavior:
[image]

I've created a tailwind playground that shows the behavior here: https://play.tailwindcss.com/psM22NgfLj

Comment: I'm struggling to understand what you're trying to achieve here. You state that the behaviour is off, but how? What isn't working the way you expect it to? Perhaps you could annotate a screenshot?

Comment: @NathanDawson Went ahead and added an image. I annotated the actual page so I had thought that's enough, my apologies.

Comment: @NathanDawson So my goal was to have the main div set the pages height, background, etc and have that scale with all content. The second div I was using as a layout - set a max width for all content, padding, center the content. The third div was meant to contain additional content in the future. I wanted it to take up the whole container and then had plans to center that content within the container. Hope this clarifies a bit better!

Comment: I've posted an answer based on my understanding of your problem at the time. So the content (bg-gray-700) is supposed to occupy the remaining height of the page? Assuming your content is longer than the viewport, should the entire page scroll or just the contents of the content box?

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/puO28eS 
Here's a clarifying image that hopefully explains it some more. Assuming the content is larger than the viewport, the entire page should scroll; that's the solution I came up with just using `overflow-scroll` and `min-h-screen`.

Comment: Updated to address your response.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On the top level container, you have `min-h-screen` which means the container should always be at least as tall as the viewport. You also have `h-0` which isn't helpful. The first step would be to remove your fixed height. By setting the height to 0, the container is fixed to no greater than the height of the screen, impacting your scroll behaviour.

Next up, remove all occurrences of `h-full`.

The first child container, with `bg-gray-800`, was set to `h-full` so my assumption is that you want that to also be at least full height. Set flex on the top-level container.

https://play.tailwindcss.com/V4amySWzDs

---

Update: Based on your feedback, I've set the third-level content container to take up at least the remainder of the page height.

https://play.tailwindcss.com/DNSQwgRMzf

That was done by applying flex to the `bg-gray-800` container, changing the direction to column, and putting `flex-1` on the content that needs to expand to fill the remainder of the height.

Comment: Could you explain the decision to remove all occurrences of `h-full`? How does that impact the outcome to not be correct?

Comment: `h-full` sets an element's height to 100%. There's quite a bit of nuance to it though and it often doesn't behave in quite the way you'd expect it to. It's the reason you kept getting background clipping. Elements were being set to be larger than their parent container.